# How to show random image from a user post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I want to display a image from a user post.
I try this:

```
<%= image_tag @user.posts.image_url(:thumb).order("rand()").limit(1) %>
```

But I have this error : "undefined method `image_url'"
I dont understand why because when I would like to display a image post its

```
<%= image_tag post.image_url %>
```

Comment: Rather than put that logic into the view, figure out the filename in the controller and pass it into the view. Views should load and display as quickly as possible; UI tests show that people won't use pages that are slow to load so it's important to make all the lookups and computations before the page starts loading.

Comment: Yes ok, but You don't answer my question..

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer it. I'm trying to help your general programming. That's something we do on SO, try to educate and improve your overall programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#image_url` is a method on an individual Post, but here you're trying to call it on a collection of Posts (`@user.posts` returns an ActiveRecord::Relation). Try swapping `limit(1)` for `first` (which will run execute the same SQL), and move `#image_url` to the end of the call chain. That way it'll fetch a single Post, and then call `#image_url` on that.

```
image_tag @user.posts.order("rand()").first.image_url(:thumb)
```

But as the Tin Man suggests, it's generally better to put queries in Controllers. It won't actually make any difference in performance, but it is more standard practice, it'll help if/when others read your code.

```
# in Controller

def action_name
  # ...
  @random_image_url = @user.posts.order("rand()").first.image_url(:thumb)
end

# in view

image_tag @random_image_url
```

Comment: It doesn't always help performance, but it does help keep the code cleaner. There are situations when a page load can stall if some process is dragging, and that's even worse for the user, then the site, when the user refuses to use the page and looks elsewhere.